# Adding strings to array in same key

Tags: php

I've an array `$url[0]` it contains many strings.
Is it possible to add manually more strings inside `url[0]` array?
They should be added in `$url[0]` and not in `$url[1]` `$url[2]` etc..

Sorry if I explain it vague, idk how to explain it beter.

Comment: Do you mean like if you used [array_unshift](http://php.net/array_unshift)?

Comment: `$url[0][] = $newString;` or `array_push($url[0], $newString);`

Comment: if $url[0] is an array : $url[0][] = 'string';

Comment: if $url[0] present an array so you can add a new value like this $url[0][]="a new value";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we dont know what `$url[0]` looks like (an array of strings/ or just plain bunch of strings). You could do something like this.

```
// initial array with many strings
$url[0] = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
$going_to_be_added = array('string4', 'string5', 'string6');
foreach($going_to_be_added as $string) {
    $url[0][] = $string;
}


// but if you mean $url[0] = 'string1 string2 string3'

$url[0] = 'string1 string2 string3';
$going_to_be_added = array('string4', 'string5', 'string6');
foreach($going_to_be_added as $string) {
    $url[0] .= $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$url[0]` is an array of strings:

```
$url[0][] = 'new string';
```

or

```
array_push($url[0], 'new string');
```

Comment: Both examples didn't work for me, however I tried doing it like this: 
`$url[0] .= "new string";` this seem to work.